# Deleting the first occurrence of a value in a stack

Tags: java, list, stack

Is there a way to delete the first occurrence in a stack. I tried to do it but it's not hitting me. I started with the method but I'm sure it's not all what should be done.

This is my approach:

```
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.stackTop() != value) {
                s1.push(this.stackTop());
                return;
            }
            this.pop();
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: that's not exactly the point of a stack, would a `List` be more appropriate ?

Comment: @R.LM It would be 100% more appropriate, but I have exams on stacks and queues and I am practicing as much as possible on various methods that I may be asked about, so I don't know if my instructor would trick us and asks us such questions.

Comment: My approach would be really heavy, but it would consist in filling an other stack without the occurences to remove, and reversing it in a third stack. Want me to answer or not as it may not be the best way ? However, hope you won't get this as it is pointless

Answer (score 1):

This shows how you would could it if you used the Java API version of a Stack.  I show a recursive method that would work for any stack that holds objects.  However, your stack implementation does not appear to use generics which means that it probably holds primitives (based on the way you are comparing values). But the method at the end of this answer will probably work as since it appears you have the methods `push(), pop(), and isEmpty()` in your implementation.  You may have to change `equals` to `==` in the comparison and remove generic type specifiers from the method declaration.

Well, you can do it like this.  But it really depends on what you mean by first.  Whether from a pop perspective or from an iterator perspective.  They are different in a stack.  `Stack` subclasses `Vector` which subclasses `AbstractList`.  So methods from those interfaces are inherited and available for use (except in some cases where they might be overridden and made unavailable).  Best to check the JavaDoc for usage.

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        stack.push(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(stack);
stack.remove(Integer.valueOf(4));  // remove "first" 4.
System.out.println(stack);
```

prints

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To remove that the first one that would be popped,  you can do it like this.

```
int i = stack.lastIndexOf(Integer.valueOf(4));
System.out.println(stack.remove(i)); // removes "last" 4
```

Remember that `Stack.remove(int)` removes the object at the specified index where `Stack.remove(Integer)` removes the first encountered Integer Object.  Not a big deal unless your stack contains integers.

If you don't want to use built in methods other than `push()` or `pop()` you can do it recursively like so.  This removes the first one encountered via `pop()`.

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack();
for (String s : List.of("A", "B", "C", "B", "R", "S", "D")) {
    stack.push(s);
}

System.out.println(stack);
deleteFirst(stack, "B");
System.out.println(stack);
```

prints

```
[A, B, C, B, R, S, D]
[A, B, C, R, S, D]
```

This continues to invoke the method until the resultant value is found. It then returns and pushes the others on the `call stack` back on the supplied stack, effectively deleting the selected item.

```
public static <T> void deleteFirst(Stack<T> stack, T val) {
    T current;
    if (stack.isEmpty()) {   // stack either empty to start
                             // or value not found
        return;
    }
    current = stack.pop();   // get next value
    if (current.equals(val)) {
        return;              // return if equals (effectively delete)
    }
    deleteFirst(stack, val); // otherwise, keep trying      
    stack.push(current);     // return other values back to stack
}
```